# iOS Flashcard swipe logic

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to build a simple flashcard app for my University project and I can't figure out the swipe logic. I am trying to swipe between two UIViews using a panGesture.

The first image is my swipe logic.

In the second image I dragged the red flashcard to the left and line 104 and 105 are called. In line 105 I am trying to change the var card to equal self.flashcard2 which is the green flashcard.

In the third image I start to drag the green flashcard. When I start dragging line 84 is called making the red flashcard show up and move around.

[Image 1 2 and 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXnp5.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this problem or have any suggestions for a better way of swiping the flashcards? Sorry if my description was confusing. Just comment if you need a better explanation. Also sorry for the picture quality. I can't share three photos until I have 10 rep points.

Comment: Please do not post code as images. Copy and paste code as text into your question. Images can't be searched or referenced.

Comment: take a look at this repo : https://github.com/ameizi/awesome-ios-animation

Comment: @rmaddy gotcha sorry I'm a newbie

Comment: That's fine. No need to apologize. Simply [edit] your question.